# Is it possible to avoid implicit any passing down a parameter to a children component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have a component passing down a parameter to the children:

```
<Nav id="header" onDown="body" active>
  {isActive => <Header isActive={isActive} />}
</Nav>
```

It is working fine but VSCode is complaining about the type:

> Parameter 'isActive' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.

It is possible to fix by adding a doc string but I'm looking for a clever way to avoid adding it for each component using `<Nav />` and make it clean:

```
<Nav id="header" onDown="body" active>
  {
    /**
    * @param {boolean} isActive
    */
    isActive => <Header isActive={isActive} />
  }
</Nav>
```

`Nav` component implementation:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import useNav from './use-nav'

/**
 * 
 * @param {Object} props
 * @param {Function} props.children
 * @param {string} props.id
 * @param {string} [props.onUp]
 * @param {string} [props.onDown]
 * @param {string} [props.onLeft]
 * @param {string} [props.onRight]
 * @param {boolean} [props.active]
 * @returns {React.ReactElement} Nav
 */
const Nav = ({ children, ...props}) => children(useNav(props))

export default Nav
```

Complete code is here https://github.com/iepsen/react-nav/tree/v1.0.0

Thank you.